# Box2d's SetLinearVelocity not working as expected

Tags: c++, physics, box2d, sfml

I'm working in a SFML and Box2d project, and I stumbled with a problem related to the linear velocity of bodies.

I've created a simplified version of the project, and the problem still persists, this is the code:

```
int main()
{    
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800.f, 800.f), "SPACE BATTLE");

    sf::Event evnt;

    sf::Clock clock;
    
    b2BodyDef bodyDefinition;
    bodyDefinition.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    b2Body* body = world.CreateBody(&bodyDefinition);

    b2PolygonShape bodyShape;
    bodyShape.SetAsBox(2.f, 2.f);

    b2FixtureDef bodyFixture;
    bodyFixture.shape = &bodyShape;
    bodyFixture.density = 1;
    bodyFixture.friction = 0.3;

    body->CreateFixture(&bodyFixture);


    body->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(0.f, 5000.f));

    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        while (window.pollEvent(evnt))
        {

            if (evnt.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        auto time = clock.getElapsedTime();

        world.Step(time.asSeconds(), 6, 2);

        clock.restart();
    }
}
```

After the first call to `world.Step()`, if I try to get the linear velocity of the body, it will be totally different than what I set before `body->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(0.f, 5000.f));`.

For example, sometimes I get `522.23f`, these values can vary, but they are always different than what I set the linear velocity to be before the main loop starts, why is this happening?